# Retrieving image from SQLite Database (BLOB data type)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, blob

I have tried to retrieve the byte[] from my SQLite DB using the code:

```
public byte[] getImageData() throws SQLException{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT AVATAR_IMAGE FROM AVATAR_TABLE WHERE AVATAR_ID = 1", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(1);
    return blob;
}
```

Error returned:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:241292 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.physicalactivity/com.example.physicalactivity.ProfileActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT AVATAR_IMAGE FROM AVATAR_TABLE WHERE AVATAR_ID = 1
```

returns only 1 column and since the column indices in a cursor are `0` based, you should retrieve it with:

```
byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(0);
```

Also, you should use `moveToFirst()` to check if the cursor returned any rows before retrieving the column's value:

```
byte[] blob = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) blob = cursor.getBlob(0);
return blob;
```